# Specify Left, Top Coordinates in ItemsControl with Shape Items

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having issues binding an ItemsControl to a collection that already contains shapes. I don't need a DataTemplate, but I want to specify the Top/Left location of the items contained in the collection.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="regions" DataContext="{Binding Path=Model}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Yellow" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>

public Model Model {get;}
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Element> Items {get;}
}
public class Element : Shape
{
    public override System.Windows.Media.Geometry Geometry {get;}
}
```

I tried using the ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle, but I got this binding error:

```
                      <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Geometry.Bounds.Left}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Geometry.Bounds.Top}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Geometry' property not found on 'object' ''Model' (HashCode=41545796)'. BindingExpression:Path=Geometry.Bounds.Top; DataItem='Model' (HashCode=41545796); target element is 'Element' (Name=''); target property is 'Top' (type 'Double')
```

It looks like the Geometry property is being applied to the Model, rather than the Element.

I added a Converter for debug purposes:

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" />
```

When I set a breakpoint in DebugConverter, the passed in "object" is of type Model rather than the Element. This seems wrong, I would expect it to be the element. How do get the Element?

Comment: Apparently your data item class is for some reason not Element, but Model (see `DataItem='Model'` in the binding error message). That does not correspond to the code you're showing here.

Comment: Besides that, `public Model Model = new Model();` does not declare a property, which would be required for `DataContext="{Binding Path=Model}"`. Remove that DataContext declaration and try `<Window.DataContext><local:Model></Window.DataContext>` instead.

Comment: Actually, Styles in WPF just doesn't know about real DataContext and there is no way to change it. So just ignore that error. Style looks ok. You can also 'qualify' property type: `Value="{Binding (Element.Geometry).Bounds.Left}"`

Comment: @cdmnk The DataContext of the elements in an ItemContainerStyle of an ItemsControl is set to the current data item, i.e. the appropriate element from the ItemsSource collection. It should be an `Element` instance here.

Comment: @Clemens should be, yes. And will be, in fact. But there's no way to tell VS Designer that. It knows only about DataContext in ItemsControl instead

Comment: @cdmnk The binding error message appears at runtime. There's no mention of VS Designer in the question.

Comment: @Clemens ok, then we should know more, because code here is acceptable

Comment: @Clemens @cdmnk I added some additional information; I'm puzzled why the "item" is the model rather than the element.  The `=new Model()` was my bad attempt at short hand to denote that it was instantiated in the code behind rather than in the Xaml.

Comment: @MarkJohnson From the binding error message we already knew that the data item is Model instead of Element, so your converter doesn't reveal anything new. From what you've shown in your post, the data item must be of type Element. Otherwise there's not enough information to further analyze your problem.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a known issue with the DataContext being "reset" on an ItemContainerStyle because it is evaluated before the binding occurs. I ended up just explicitly calling Canvas.SetLeft() and Canvas.SetTop() when I construct the model. Not an ideal solution, but it worked.

Comment: Please provide a link to the "known issue".